MLFlow & Lightning - Epochs and steps not logging properly
I use Lightning to set up and train my transformer network.
I use MLFlow as a logger.
The problem is, it seems to log steps and epochs inconsistently.
Here is what I obtain for a few metrics:

Here is how it is done in my code. I create the logger:
logger = MLFlowLogger(
            experiment_name=config['logger']['experiment_name'], 
            tracking_uri=config['logger']['tracking_uri'],
            log_model=config['logger']['log_model']
        )

That I pass to my trainer:
trainer = Trainer(
    accelerator=config['accelerator'],
    devices=config['devices'],
    max_epochs=config['max_epochs'],
    logger=logger,
    log_every_n_steps=50,
    callbacks=[early_stopping, lr_monitor, checkpoint, progress_bar],
)

Metrics are logged in the training_step and validation_step functions:
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx): 
    index, audio_name, targets, inputs = batch
    logits = self.model(inputs) 
    loss = self.loss(logits, targets)
    predictions = torch.argmax(logits, dim=1)
    self.train_accuracy.update(predictions, targets)
    self.log("training_loss", loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size, prog_bar=True)
    self.log("training_accuracy", self.train_accuracy, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size)
    self.log("training_gpu_allocation", torch.cuda.memory_allocated(), on_step=True, on_epoch=False)        
    return {"inputs":inputs, "targets":targets, "predictions":predictions, "loss":loss}

        
def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    index, audio_name, targets, inputs = batch
    logits = self.model(inputs)
    loss = self.loss(logits, targets)
    predictions = torch.argmax(logits, dim=1)
    self.validation_accuracy(predictions, targets)
    self.validation_precision(predictions, targets)
    self.validation_recall(predictions, targets)
    self.validation_f1_score(predictions, targets)
    self.validation_confmat.update(predictions, targets)
    self.log("validation_loss", loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size, prog_bar=True)
    self.log("validation_accuracy", self.validation_accuracy, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size)
    self.log("validation_precision", self.validation_precision, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size)
    self.log("validation_recall", self.validation_recall, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size)
    self.log("validation_f1_score", self.validation_f1_score, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size) 

As you can see, for the epoch-steps plot, there are points at the following steps: 49, 199, 349, 499, ... I would expect my first step to be 0 and to have a point each 50 steps as I asked my trainer with the log_every_n_step=50.
Morever, metrics only logged on_epoch only show just one value in plots. I can't see the values of previous epochs.
Not sure if it is a lightning or an mlflow problem. But I am not doing anything exotic here.
Anyone with MLFlow+Lightning experience here?
